# How to block torrent downloads in my beetel 450tc2 router?

Tags: networking, modem, bittorrent, utorrent

How Can I Block torrent downloads using Beetel 450TC2 Modem in my home network. I tried using QoS, but got stuck in between. Can some one explain the procedure step by step
[image: Modem Configuration Page]

Comment: You can't with the modem.  You would need a router that supports custom firmware like DD-WRT or OpenWRT to accomplish your goals.

Comment: Disable upnp in the router if you can, then delete any port forwarding entries in the router. You can still port forward but is has to be manually entered in the router and if it is password protected others cannot configure port forwarding which will block torrent clients from working.